# Is there a way to run grid.py without running gnuplot?

Tags: python, libsvm

Is there a way to execute grid.py without running gnuplot? I would rather not display the plots or warnings associate with the program.

Comment: are you talking about the grid.py from wxPython? or ??

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- I assume it's from `libsvm` (whatever that is) based on the tag ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's the source of `grid.py`](https://github.com/dougalsutherland/libsvm/blob/master/tools/grid.py) (in my github mirror of the `libsvm` code).

It's not very customizable; there's some options done by silly manual parsing instead of `optparse`/etc, and the path to `gnuplot` is even hardcoded; no options not to draw. But it shouldn't be hard to modify the file and just rip out all the gnuplot-related code.

In fact, I think all you have to do is comment out the last line of `process_options`

```
gnuplot = Popen(gnuplot_exe,stdin = PIPE).stdin
```

and the calls to `redraw()` near the end of `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you call grid.py, simply replace the path parameter with "null".

For example, instead of:

```
cmd = '{0} -svmtrain "{1}" -gnuplot "{2}" "{3}"'.format(grid_py, svmtrain_exe, gnuplot_exe, scaled_file)
```

Use:

```
cmd = '{0} -svmtrain "{1}" -gnuplot "{2}" "{3}"'.format(grid_py, svmtrain_exe, "null", scaled_file)
```